# A double binomial sum: looking for a combinatorial proof of an identity.

Tags: combinatorics

While solving a problem I came across the following identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac m2\right\rfloor}
\binom nk\binom{n-k}{m-2k}2^{m-2k}
=\binom{2n}m,
$$
somewhat resembling the Vandermonde's one.

The form of the identity suggests existence of a combinatorial proof. Any related hints and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$\binom{2n}m$ is the number of subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ of size $m$. Consider the intersection of $S$ with the sets $E_i=\{2i-1,2i\}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. To choose a set $S$, first choose the set of $i$ for which $|S\cap E_i|=2$, then choose the set of $i$ for which $|S\cap E_i|=1$.

Comment: I think for the sake of completeness you should add that the second choice is in fact double: one should not only choose $E_i$ but also the parity of the chosen element (i.e. either $2i-1$ or $2i$).

Comment: @user For a hint, incompleteness is part of the goal :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider binary words of length $2n$ that contain $m$ $0$'s. Index the entries with $1_a,2_a, \cdots , n_a, 1_b,2_b, \cdots , n_b$. Let $A_{00}$ be the subset of $[n]$ whose elements $i$ have both $i_a$ and $i_b$ equal to $0$ & Let $A_{01}$ be the subset of $[n]$ whose elements $i$ have one $i_a$ and $i_b$ equal to $0$ and the other equal to $1$.

$A_{00}$ has cardinality $k=0, \cdots , \left\lfloor\frac m2\right\rfloor$ and $A_{01}$ has cardinality $m-2k$ and these can be the $a$ or $b$ entry in $2^{n-2k}$ ways. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac m2\right\rfloor}
\binom nk\binom{n-k}{m-2k}2^{m-2k}
=\binom{2n}m.
\end{eqnarray*}